# Weyl semimetal where dispersion crosses Weyl point energy not at Weyl point

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators, weyl-semimetal

Consider a two-band tight-binding Weyl semimetal model $$H=\sum_\alpha a_\alpha(\vec k)\,\sigma_\alpha$$ for $\alpha=0,1,2,3$. For instance, one with one pair of Weyl points (WPs) could be $$H=\sin{k_x}\sigma_1+\sin{k_y}\sigma_2+(\cos{k_x}+\cos{k_y}+\cos{k_z}-\cos{k_w}-2)\sigma_3$$
with WPs at $(0,0,\pm k_w)$.

I want to construct a simple model that satisfies the following condition:
i) The energy band crosses the WP energy ($\varepsilon=0$) at some momentum away from the WPs. ii) This effect does not come from $a_0$ term.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please clarify what is $k_w$?

Comment: @E.Anikin Updated.

Comment: For a 2-band model without an a_0 term, the only way it can cross zero energy is if all $a_\alpha$ are zero, which gives you another Weyl node (or multiple superimposed on each other). This can be done, and it seems like there is no other way to do it. Do you agree?

Comment: @NandagopalManoj Yes, if only $\vec{a}=0$. But I was wondering if this can otherwise be something different from a WP.

Comment: If at some $\vec{k}_0$ the vector $\vec{a}(\vec{k}_0)$ is zero and the jacobian $\frac{\partial a_\alpha}{\partial k_\beta}$ is degenerate, the spectrum in the vicinity of $\vec{k}_0$ is not like the spectrum for a Weyl point. Chern number at such points may be not $\pm 1$.

Comment: @E.Anikin isn't that equivalent to two (or more) Weyl points superimposed on top of each other? The Jacobian being degenerate implies quadratic (or higher-order) band touching along some direction in $k$-space.

A simple example can be obtained by modifying OP's Hamiltonian by setting $a_3 = (\cos kx + \cos ky + \cos kz − \cos kw −2)^2$.

Comment: @NandagopalManoj  I think it is, you are right. I just suggested a more accurate formulation of what is "several Weyl points superimposed on top of each other".